# Unable to reset VRAM or boot a 2007 MacBook in Safe Mode or otherwise

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, startup

Recently I made a hasty mistake in forcing a shutdown when it was becoming unresponsive. Previously I've been able to boot the system with no problems by starting in single user mode (to bypass the gray progress bar (which disappears after loading partially) and spinning wheel that stays indefinitely). However, now when starting up the system, it appears that pressed keys aren't recognized.

I've tried resetting the SMC (by unplugging the power source and battery and holding down the power button for 5 seconds), but that appeared not to help.

Is there another way to get to single-user mode or reset the NVRAM (such as by opening and adjusting something in the MacBook)?

EDIT:  I attempted diagnostics based on comments below by trying to boot into Verbose mode and holding <kbd>Option</kbd> to bring up the bootloader, but nothing worked.

Comment: `Command-Option-P-R` doesn't work?  Now, the fact that you have to boot to single mode to boot your Mac is concerning...why didn't you address the problem earlier?

Comment: `Command-Option-P-R` didn't work. It didn't seem to be much of a problem earlier, as running fsck functions from single-user mode appeared to work well (I only had to do this a couple times) and everything was working when running the system.

Comment: Exactly what happens when you try to boot your Mac?

Comment: There is a hardware noise (I always remember hearing when starting the Mac), and no software noise. There is a white screen after a second, followed by the apple logo a second later, followed by the progress bar and wheel a couple seconds later.

Comment: Try holding `Cmd-V` (Verbose Mode) and see what get's output to the console.  Look for error messages.  Also, do you have your original install disks to run Apple Hardware Test?

Comment: I'll try Verbose Mode and check for the disks (although I doubt I have them)

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that command it's working either. I was hoping that a worst case scenario might entail opening the computer and making an adjustment other than replacing the hard drive which isn't an option for me (I thought I remembered something like that as a potential solution, but may very well be wrong)

Comment: Just for giggles, try holding `Option` to see if it brings up your boot loader.  If it dosen't your keyboard may be hosed; try an external one.  If that doesn't work, it's time to start looking at repair shops because there's nothing that can be adjusted.  If you can't boot to Verbose mode or to the boot loader, replacing a drive won't help.

Comment: (you can ignore if this is the case) I also assume that letting the computer run with the spinning wheel will accomplish nothing (especially if it runs for a day and nothing happens), as there is probably some IO error loop that it's stuck in

Comment: I don't know if/when I would have thought of the usb keyboard solution, but this worked when learned that the windows logo operates as mac's command button. Thank you; feel free to post as an answer if you like at your convenience.

Comment: Thanks. I take it for granted that `Alt` = `Option`  but I am glad you were able to get your situation addressed.  If you still need to fix your constantly having to boot to Safe Mode, that can be another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your keyboard may not be functioning properly.

If pressing <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> doesn't get you into verbose mode but you can can no longer get into Safe Mode (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) there may be something wrong with the keyboard.

Try an external USB keyboard to issue the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reset the NVRAM.  (<kbd>Alt</kbd> = <kbd>Option</kbd>)

That should allow you to reset your NVRAM.  At this point you should test out the built-in keyboard and if it still isn't working, it's time to look at getting it replaced.

Comment: For the record (if this may help someone), the keyboard apparently stopped working due to a battery that began bulging. It had been kept out, but I think it was recently placed back in because it was thought to have fixed a backlight issue I was having.